# How to show date in message box only date unique to the previous date in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want show unique date in message chat
Example.

```
data() {
 return {
  message: [
    {id: 1,message: 'hi', created_at: '2023-02-16 00:44:41'},
    {id: 2,message: 'how are you?', created_at: '2023-02-16 01:00:00'},
    {id: 3,message: 'hello', created_at: '2023-03-01 12:00:00'},
    {id: 5,message: 'hi', created_at: '2023-03-01 15:56:00'},
  ]
 }}
```

example result date in message 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should format the date property.
You can create a function:

```
formattedDate(date) {
  const dateObj = new Date(date)
  return dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US')
}
```

Then in your template when calling the date prop, you can send it as function property. For example:

```
<ul>
<li v-for="message in messages" :key="message.id">
{{ formattedDate(message.created_at) }}
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an additional prop for your messages array, for example "show_date". This prop will determine whether to show the date or not.

**You can do it by computed value:**

```
computed: {
  messages() {
    return this.message.map((m, index) => {
      // Get previous message from source array
      const prevMessage = this.message[index - 1];
      if (prevMessage) { // If previous message exists let's check the dates
        return {...m, show_date: !this.isSameDate(m.created_at, prevMessage.created_at) };
      } else { // otherwise we will show the date
        return {...m, show_date: true };
      }
    });
  },
},
```

**Here is the func for check if dates are the same day, but you can use momentjs or dayjs instead**

```
methods: {
  isSameDate(first, second) {
    const firstDate = new Date(first);
    const secondDate = new Date(second);
    return firstDate.getFullYear() === secondDate.getFullYear() && 
      firstDate.getMonth() === secondDate.getMonth() && 
      firstDate.getDate() === secondDate.getDate();
  },
},
```

**And finally, you have to render messages by the computed prop and display date only if 'show_date' is true.**

```
<div v-for="m in messages" :key="m.id">
  <div v-if="m.show_date">
    {{ m.created_at }}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{ m.message }}
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find full code here: https://codepen.io/AlekseiKrivo/pen/xxyXpmY